# Get an array of class names for a Playwright element

Tags: typescript, playwright

What is the most effective way to get an array of all class names for an element in Playwright using TypeScript?

I cannot seem to find any API for this very typical task and had to write the following:

```
export const getClassNames = async (locator: Locator): Promise<string[]> => {
    // Make sure that we exctly one element
    await expect(locator).toHaveCount(1);

    // Get the element
    const element = locator.first();

    // Use evaluateHandle to get an array of class names for the element
    const classListHandle = await element.evaluateHandle((el: Element) => Array.from(el.classList));

    // Get the result from the classListHandle
    const classNames = await classListHandle.jsonValue() as string[];

    return classNames;
};
```

Comment: please share your code and illustrate what you have tried  so far where you are getting issues.Currently It's not clear what you are doing and what's your goal.

Comment: This would help you in getting faster responses.

Comment: I've added my custom function but I actually wanted to ask if there is really no existing API in Playwright itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be such a function at the time of writing, but you can shorten your code considerably:

```js
export const getClassNames = (locator: Locator): Promise<string[]> =>
  locator.evaluate(el => [...el.classList]);
```

If you're running in strict mode, `.evaluate` already asserts that there's a single element, and there's no need for intermediate ElementHandles which Playwright generally advises against using.

Here's a runnable proof of concept:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // 1.30.0

const classList = loc => loc.evaluate(el => [...el.classList]);

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setContent(`<p class="a b c"></p>`);
  console.log(await classList(page.locator("p"))); // => [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

  await page.setContent(`<p></p><p></p>`);
  console.log(await classList(page.locator("p")));
    // => strict mode violation: locator('p') resolved to 2 elements
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

But if you're doing this for the purposes of a testing assertion, use

```js
await expect(locator).toHaveClass(["some", "classes"]);
```

as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76035882/6243352) instead.

Comment: I would have hoped for Playwright to have something like this already build-in as the DOM already provides a standardised way to access the classList

Comment: Playwright doesn't have macros for every DOM property, just some of the common ones. I think that's a good thing--the API is already rather bloated relative to Puppeteer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are verifying on element's classes, an neat way:

```
const locator = page.locator('list > .component');
await expect(locator).toHaveClass(['component', 'component selected', 'component']);
```

You may also use regular expression in this:

```
await expect(locator).toHaveClass(/selected/);
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-class